# how to create new array based on condition in key , value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a array like this and I want a desired output based on username and number of services booked by user. I want data such as  number of quantity of services related to  username

```
[
    {
        
        "customerNo": 1001,
        "username": "user3",
        "serviceName": "Tempo",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
       ,
        "customerNo": 1002,
        "username": "user4",
        "serviceName": "Social",
        "quantity": 1,
       
    },
    {
        "customerNo": 1001,
        "username": "user3",
        "serviceName": "Mango",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "customerNo": 1001,
        "username": "user3",
        "serviceName": "Mango",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "customerNo": 1003,
        "username": "user5",
        "serviceName": "Social",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "customerNo": 1002,
        "username": "user4",
        "serviceName": "Social",
        "quantity": 1,
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        
        "customerNo": 1001,
        "username": "user3",
        "serviceName": "Tempo",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        
        "customerNo": 1001,
        "username": "user3",
        "serviceName": "Mango",
        "quantity": 2,
    },
    {
       
        "customerNo": 1002,
        "username": "user4",
        "serviceName": "Social",
        "quantity": 2,
       
    },
    {
        "customerNo": 1003,
        "username": "user5",
        "serviceName": "Social",
        "quantity": 1,
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

I did tried for `forEach` and `reduce` but could not get desired result may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: If you post the code you have tried, somebody might be able to tell you if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: IF you want `output based on username and number of services booked by user` it seems like you would want a username/id with a child array containing the various service name(s) / qty(s). As it is you are not producing that? Maybe I am misunderstanding the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Sort based on `customerNo`
2. Remove duplicates with added quantity (?)

There you go:

```js
const userLogs = [{
    "customerNo": 1001,
    "username": "user3",
    "serviceName": "Tempo",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "customerNo": 1002,
    "username": "user4",
    "serviceName": "Social",
    "quantity": 1,

  },
  {
    "customerNo": 1001,
    "username": "user3",
    "serviceName": "Mango",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "customerNo": 1001,
    "username": "user3",
    "serviceName": "Mango",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "customerNo": 1003,
    "username": "user5",
    "serviceName": "Social",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "customerNo": 1002,
    "username": "user4",
    "serviceName": "Social",
    "quantity": 1,
  }
]

// Sort based on customerNo
userLogs.sort((a, b) => a.customerNo - b.customerNo);

// console.log(userLogs)

let aggregatedValues = {};

let aggregatedArray = userLogs.map((item) => {
  // Check if an already exists
  if (aggregatedValues[item.customerNo + item.serviceName]) {
    // If it does, increment the quantity
    aggregatedValues[item.customerNo + item.serviceName].quantity += item.quantity;
  } else {
    // If it doesn't, add a new object
    aggregatedValues[item.customerNo + item.serviceName] = {
      customerNo: item.customerNo,
      username: item.username,
      serviceName: item.serviceName,
      quantity: item.quantity,
    };
  }
});

let finalArray = Object.values(aggregatedValues).reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push(item);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(finalArray)
```

Edit: Corrected code suggestion by @3limin4t0r

Comment: The desired result requires `user3` `Mango` to have `quantity` `2`.

Comment: Changed code, thanks. I did not see it at all at first.

Comment: I appreciate your time to take and provide the solution. thanks. @jishan Shaikh  that is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Both forEach and reduce are not the right methods to go with. As Pointy, mentioned, you should include your code so others can get an exact idea of what you're doing. It sounds like you may be looking for the .filter() method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

so may look like something like this

```
const filteredArray = unfliteredArray.filter(element => element.userName === "user3")
```

I suggest you don't hardcode your username, but this is just an example.